# How can I debug a Flask application that has a custom exception handler?

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling, flask

I would like to implement an exception handler for my Flask application that displays a custom error page when an `Exception` is thrown. I can get this working easily with

```
@application.errorhandler(Exception)
def http_error_handler(error):
    return flask.render_template('error.html', error=error), 500
```

but this has the side effect of catching all exceptions before they hit the debugger (either the Werkzeug debugger or my IDE's) so that debugging is effectively disabled.

How can I implement a custom exception handler that still allows be to debug exceptions and errors? Is there a way to disable my custom handler when in debug mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Werkzeug will generate a 500 exception when an uncaught exception propagates.  Create an error handler for `500`, not for `Exception`.  The 500 handler is bypassed when debugging is enabled.

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def handle_internal_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html', error=e), 500
```

The following is a full app that demonstrates that the error handler works for assert, raise, and abort.

```
from flask import Flask, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(500)
def handle_internal_error(e):
    return 'got an error', 500

@app.route('/assert')
def from_assert():
    assert False

@app.route('/raise')
def from_raise():
    raise Exception()

@app.route('/abort')
def from_abort():
    abort(500)

app.run()
```

Going to all three urls (/assert, /raise, and /abort) will show the message "got an error".  Running with `app.run(debug=True)` will only show the message for /abort since that is an "expected" response; the other two urls will show the debugger.